# Constructing JSON with children

Tags: javascript, php, json, handsontable

I am trying to construct my JSON to look like so...with the `__children: [` coming right after `Qty Shipped: null,`

```
[
    {
        'Job Number': '22983321',
        'LN #': null,
        'Description': null,
        'Qty': null,
        'AS400 Ship Date': null,
        'Date Showed on Report': null,
        'Days to Manufacture': null,
        'Notes': null,
        'Date Shown Completed': null,
        'Actual Ship Date': null,
        'Qty Shipped': null,
        __children: [
            {
                //values here
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

With my current code what I am getting is this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "Job Number": "22359501",
        "LN #": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Qty": null,
        "AS400 Ship Date": null,
        "Date Showed on Report": null,
        "Days to Manufacture": null,
        "Notes": null,
        "Date Shown Completed": null,
        "Actual Ship Date": null,
        "Qty Shipped": null
    },
    "_children": [
        {
            //values here
        },
    ]
}
```

This is my current code:

```
$checkJob = '';

//output data into spreadsheet view
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
    if ($checkJob == $job_number) {
        //print "<b>checkJob: " . $checkJob . " | " . "currentJob: " . $job_number . "</b><br>";
        $json['__children'][] = array(
            'LN #' => $line_item,
            'Description' => $description,
            'Qty' => $qty,
            'AS400 Ship Date' => $as400_ship_date,
            'Date Showed on Report' => $date_showed_on_report,
            'Days to Manufacture' => "5",
            'Notes' => $notes,
            'Date Shown Completed' => $date_shown_complete,
            'Actual Ship Date' => $actual_ship_date,
            'Qty Shipped' => $qty_shipped
        );
    }
    else {
        $checkJob = $job_number;
        //print "checkJob: " . $checkJob . " | " . "currentJob: " . $job_number . "<br>";
        $json[] = array(
            'Job Number' => $job_number,
            'LN #' => null,
            'Description' => null,
            'Qty' => null,
            'AS400 Ship Date' => null,
            'Date Showed on Report' => null,
            'Days to Manufacture' => null,
            'Notes' => null,
            'Date Shown Completed' => null,
            'Actual Ship Date' => null,
            'Qty Shipped' => null,
        );
    }
}
```

I tried changing `$json[][] = array(` to `$json['__children'][] = array(` and it's still not structuring the JSON correctly. I am trying to build the JSON using built in functions as suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the data, checking if there is the base data set for each job number (using `isset()`) and then just add in the children data on each loop...

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
    if ( !isset($json[$job_number]))  {
        $json[$job_number] = array(
            'Job Number' => $job_number,
            'LN #' => null,
            'Description' => null,
            'Qty' => null,
            'AS400 Ship Date' => null,
            'Date Showed on Report' => null,
            'Days to Manufacture' => null,
            'Notes' => null,
            'Date Shown Completed' => null,
            'Actual Ship Date' => null,
            'Qty Shipped' => null,
        );
    }
    $json[$job_number]['__children'][] = array(
            'LN #' => $line_item,
            'Description' => $description,
            'Qty' => $qty,
            'AS400 Ship Date' => $as400_ship_date,
            'Date Showed on Report' => $date_showed_on_report,
            'Days to Manufacture' => "5",
            'Notes' => $notes,
            'Date Shown Completed' => $date_shown_complete,
            'Actual Ship Date' => $actual_ship_date,
            'Qty Shipped' => $qty_shipped
        );
    }
}
// Remove job number keys
$json = array_values($json);
```

Comment: Now it has no children associated with any parents.

Comment: I've updated the code, I was assuming they were added at the same time.

Comment: That did it! Is there a way to quickly put the children in ascending order?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this.

```
$json[0]['__children'] = array();
```

Comment: That made the JSON come out exactly right but it only does it for the first parent. All the parents after that it doesn't assign children to.

Comment: Is this some sort of a recursive loop? You will need to implement recursion if you have multiple levels. that wasnt mentioned in the question.

Comment: It has multiple parents...but only 1 level of children.

Comment: Here is a static example of what the data structure looks like: https://pastebin.com/Yb8jBmx8